# Kali Linux on VM requires special Kernel to run (Lenovo Thinkpad)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, kali-linux, kernel

**Will it work with 64 bit?**

64 bit Kali and 32 bit Debian on VM wasn't working.
not working

Will it work with the **Kali Linux** being 64 bit both as the **Debian**?

How do you get the 64 bit settings to show up on a VM then?

**Error and Specs / Settings**

I'm not using the appropriate Kernel, is what the error says.

Look at the picture's for errors, settings and specs.

[image: Error]

[image: Virtual box settings 1]

[image: Virtual box settings 2]

[image: Pc Specs 1]

[image: Pc Specs 2]

Comment: I can't understand what your question is... Please could you re-phrase to focus on A) What you have setup, B) What isn't working / error messages, and C) What you've tried to resolve it.

Comment: The screenshot is specifically calling out PAE as "_not present_"... [did you enable it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zlGx.png)?

Comment: You need to have hardware virtualization enabled in the BIOS.  According to your screenshot you don't. "Hyper-V - Virtualisering aktiver...Nej"  VirtualBox will only work with 32bit OSes.  64bit OSes will not run with out it.

Comment: @essjae I did finally figure out that you needed to enable Hardware Virtualization, but the problem here is that. When i go into the BIOS it's locked, Is there any other way than opening up your computer to fix it, I typed some command into the CMD to enable Hyper-V and it did work when i looked into command features. Hyper-V was enabled. Now i'm going to test the newest version of Kali Linux 32 bit with a 32 bit Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have Hyper-V enabled, VirtualBox will only allow 32bit guests.  Hyper-V blocks the hardware virtualization access from VirtualBox.  If your BIOS  is locked, you'd need the password to unlock or contact Lenovo with proof of purchase for them to reset it, if they can.